# React scrollIntoView undefined

Tags: reactjs, scroll

On button click, I want scroll to component

```
class Host extends Component {
  static contextType = HostContext;
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.dateSelectorRef = React.createRef();
  }
  setStartDate () {
     this.dateSelectorRef.current.setStartDate()
     console.log('Not working', this.dateSelectorRef.current.scrollIntoView)
  }
  render() {
     ........
     <DirectButton clickhandler={() => this.setStartDate()} />
     ........
     ........
     <DateSelector
        ref={this.dateSelectorRef}
        onStartDateChange={this.onStartDateChange}
        onEndDateChange={this.onEndDateChange}
     />
  }
```

Above code, while I click on `DirectButton` event handler `setStartDate` call
but `this.dateSelectorRef.current` have no object `scrollIntoView` (undefined)

Any Idea what am I missing.

Comment: `contextType = HostCon**strong text**text;` that's a Syntax error. Can you also make a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1):

The DateSelector component does not implement this method, this is a DOM element method. You'll need to find a way to access the ref of the DOM element rendered by this component.

Comment: it seems ref does not work on JSX component. just wrap my component is virtual HTML component and define ref on it. it works

Comment: ref works on JSX component, they just give you access to each methods of that component. In your case, you only had access to the methods that DateSelector implements.

Answer (score 0):

```
setStartDate = () => {
 this.dateSelectorRef.current.setStartDate()
 console.log('Not working', this.dateSelectorRef.current.scrollIntoView) }
```

This code will fix your issue

Comment: not working,
I already pass current component reference on click event handler using 
clickhandler={() => this.setStartDate()}